# Interactive stream plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to build a stream plot with the ability to change the parameter `beta` using the slider with matplotlib.
Here is my code for stream plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=150)
Y, X = np.mgrid[-1:1:150j, -1:1:150j]

beta = -0
U = Y
V = beta * Y + 1 * X + 1 * X**3

plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U, linewidth=1, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, density=2)
plt.scatter(0, 0, c='r')
plt.colorbar();
plt.savefig("out.png")

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$p$')
plt.title('k = omega = - 1, beta = ' + str(beta))
plt.autoscale()

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I want to get something similar to what the `Manipulate` function in Wolfram Mathematica does:
[Manipulate Stream Plot in Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A21N1.jpg)
I've tried to use this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 5
f0 = 3
delta_f = 5.0
s = a0 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
ax.margins(x=0)

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
axamp = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0, valstep=delta_f)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)


def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    freq = sfreq.val
    l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


sfreq.on_changed(update)
samp.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    sfreq.reset()
    samp.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)


def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

plt.show()
```

But I don't know how I should change line `l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, steamplots are not easily manipulated. I think your best bet is to clear the axes and redraw the streamplot at each call of update. It's not very efficient, so you may want to decrease the `density` to speed up the process.

One issue is that clearing the axes clears everything, not only the streamplot (I did not find an easy way to remove just the stream lines and arrows without touching the rest). So I created a function that does all the drawing to be called from `update`:

```py
%matplotlib widget
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

Y, X = np.mgrid[-1:1:150j, -1:1:150j]

beta = -0
U = Y
V = lambda beta: beta * Y + 1 * X + 1 * X**3

title = 'k = omega = - 1, beta = {:.3f}'


def draw_streamplot(beta,ax):
    stream = ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V(beta), color=U, linewidth=1, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, density=1)
    ax.scatter(0, 0, c='r')

    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$p$')
    ax.set_title(title.format(beta))
    ax.autoscale()
    return stream
    
    
def update(val):
    ax.cla()
    draw_streamplot(val,ax)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

stream = draw_streamplot(beta, ax)
ax.figure.colorbar(stream.lines, ax=ax)

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
bbox = ax.get_position()
axbeta = fig.add_axes([bbox.x0, bbox.y1+0.1, bbox.width, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
sbeta = Slider(axbeta, 'Beta', 0.0, 2.0, valinit=beta, valstep=0.1)
sbeta.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]